# Openness on disjoint union of metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces, solution-verification

Here is a set-up for the problem I'm trying to solve.

> Given metric spaces $X$ and $Y$, define $Z := X \sqcup Y$, and define a metric $\rho: Z \times Z \to \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$ by
> $$\rho(z_1, z_2) = \begin{cases}
> \rho_X (z_1, z_2) & \text{ if $z_1, z_2 \in X$} \\ 
> \rho_Y (z_1, z_2) & \text{ if $z_1, z_2 \in Y$} \\ 
> C & \text{ if $z_1$ and $z_2$ live in different sets}
> \end{cases}
> $$

Given $Z$ as above, I am trying to prove the following.

> Show that a subset $U \subset Z$ is open if and only if $U \cap X$ and $U \cap Y$ are open.

Here is my attempt. I can assume without loss of generality that $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint because $Z$ is defined as a disjoint union, so in the case that they weren't, I'd have to replace them with isometric copies.

> $(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $U \subset Z$ is open and fix $x \in U$. Then either $x \in X$ or $x \in Y$. Suppose first that $x \in X$. As $U$ is open, there exists $r > 0$ such that $B_r (x) \subset U$. Set $\delta := \min(r, C)$. Then $B_{\delta} (x) \cap Y = \emptyset$, because if $t \in B_{\delta} (x)$, then $\rho(x,t) < \delta \leq C$, but $\rho(x,y) = C$ for all $y \in Y$. Therefore, $B_{\delta} (x) \subset U \setminus Y$. But $U \setminus Y = U \cap X$ because $X$ and $Y$ partition $Z$. So $B_{\delta} (x) \subset U \cap X$, so $U \cap X$ is open. If $x \in Y$, then by an exactly analagous argument, interchanging labels, $B_{\delta} (x) \subset U \cap Y$, so $U \cap Y$ is open.
>
> ($\Leftarrow$) Suppose $U \cap X$ and $U \cap Y$ are open, and let $u \in U$. Without loss of generality, suppose $u \in X$, i.e., $u \in U \cap X$. As $U \cap X$ is open, there exists $r > 0$ such that $B_r (x) \subset U \cap X \subset U$, so $U$ is open.

I'm not fully comfortable with the forward direction. Am I correct that $U \setminus X = U \setminus Y$? Or is $U \setminus X = Y$? I believe the former since there can be elements of $Y$ not contained in $U$, but then the best I can say is $U \setminus X \subset Y$.

Comment: The proof looks good enough to me. However, where have you used $U \setminus X = U \setminus Y$, as mentioned in the question you asked? Anyway, that is not possible unless $U$ is empty. What you have used is $U \setminus X = U \cap Y$, which is correct since in this case you have your universe as the disjoint union of $X$ and $Y$. Thus, the elements which are in $U$ but not in $X$ (if any) must be in $Y$.

Comment: When you say $U \cap X$ and $U \cap Y$ "are open", do you mean open in $Z$ or open in $X$ and $Y$, respectively? These are not *a priori* the same thing (yes, they can be proven to be the same thing - but that is effectively what you are doing here). This is important because you appear, particularly in the back direction proof, to be treating $B_r(x)$ as the same set in both $X$ and $Z$, which it is not, if $r \ge C$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair This is a very good point. I meant to say open in $X$ and $Y$, respectively.

Comment: Then you need to modify the backwards argument to specify $0 < r < C$. Otherwise the claim that $B_r(u) \subset U \cap X$ is false in $Z$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I'm not completely sure I understand. I believe the idea is that $B_r (u)$ is an open ball with respect to $X$, not with respect to $U$, correct? I could take $\epsilon := \min(r,C)$ and consider $B_{\epsilon} (u)$, which I believe is effectively what you are suggesting, but I don't quite get how that gives an open ball in $Z$.

Comment: Ok, I think I see your point. Openness of $U \cap X$ gives an $r > 0$ such that $B_r (u) \subset U \cap X$, but $B_r (u)$ is by definition the set of $q \in X$ such that $\rho_X(q,u) < r$. I want this to be the set of $q \in Z$ such that $\rho_Z (q,u) < r$. So I can define an open ball with respect to $Z$ and just specify that $r < C$, so as to exclude elements of $Y$ anyway. Is that the idea?

Comment: Exactly, If the $r$ chosen so that $B_r(u) \subset U\cap X$ in $X$ is $\ge C$, then in $Z, B_r(u)$ will actually include all of $Y$. Unless $U$ contains all of $Y$, the statement $B_r(u) \subset U$ is false in $Z$. So you need to choose an $r < C$ for your argument to work.